# DLL - Dynamic PDF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, dynamicpdf

I am using dynamic PDF in my .net project to get .PDF and to send it for printing

My code is failing at the below line with the error message

```
eTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.DocumentLoadException: File not found or could not be opened.
at ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.InputPdf..ctor(Byte[] data)

pdfs.Add(new InputPdf(ms.ToArray()));
```

where ms is a memorystream.

In my dev environment the dynamic pdf used in for X86 based processor. ie

```
ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x86.dll.
```

Now in production environment the processor is x64.

Is the differnece in the dll cause the above error?

Also Can anyone help me to get link for DLL?

```
ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x64
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for ceTe Software, the company that develops DynamicPDF libraries.

The dll you would need to use depends on the .NET version and the target platform (x86 or x64) of your application. Refer to the following documentation [link](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Support/NET_Help_Library_16_06/webframe.html#DynamicPDFPrintManagerProgrammingWithReferencingTheAssembly.html) on the dlls provided for PrintManager. If you are using ceTe.DynamicPDF.Printing.40.x86.dll and compiling your application as 32-bit, then you should be able to use that application on both x86 and x64 machines.

The difference in the dll (x86 or x64) should not cause this type of error. This type of error is usually caused when there is some issue with the PDF document that you are trying to print. Try printing the PDF that worked on your dev machine on production and see if that works. Also, I recommend that you download the most up to date build of PrintManager available and see if it resolves the issue. If you are a licensed user, download it from the [customer area](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/CustomerArea/) by logging in with you serial number. If you are still evaluating the product and do not have a serial number, you can access the download [here](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Products/DynamicPDFPrintManagerForNET/Download.csp).

If the issue is not resolved even after you try the latest build, please email to our [support team](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Support/Index.csp) and include the following information - full exception message (including the stack trace), a copy of the PDF, code to reproduce the error & version info of the PrintManager dll you are using.